# Is an iframe's srcdoc always an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to work around a cross-origin problem with Chrome which is produced by having an iFrame tag with a src attribute that has data uri in it. I am wondering if I can work around this with the srcdoc attribute. Which is why I am curious to if the default content type for a srcdoc 'text/html'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the default content type is in fact `text/html`. According to the [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-srcdoc),

> If the srcdoc attribute is specified:
>
> Navigate the element's browsing context to **a resource whose Content-Type is text/html**, whose URL is about:srcdoc, and whose data consists of the value of the attribute. The resulting Document must be considered an iframe srcdoc document.